# Check if user has a verified email address and redirect them in Meteor

Tags: mongodb, if-statement, meteor, routes, email-verification

I need to find out whether the user who triggers a `click. event` has a verified email. In case "true" he should be redirected to another page, where he can call a server side method. In case "false" he should be redirected to a page, where he can click a button to resent a new verification link to him.

I tried to use some functions I found in other questions, but it didn´t work. Here is my code for the click. event and if function which does not work out:

```
"click. event": function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
   if (this.userId && Meteor.user().emails[0].verified)
   {
    Router.go('LinkToCallTheMethod');
     }; else 
     {
    console.log('Please verify email first');
    Router.go('LinkToResentVerificationLink');
     }
   });
```

The problem is that nothing happens. The user is not redirected even when I change the boolean in the `emails[0].verified` field to 'true' or 'false' (doesn´t matter, nothing happens), but I also do not receive any error code.

Therefore I think the problem is in the `if(...&& Meteor.user().emails[0].verified)`. Is there another way to find out whether a email is verified?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use **this.userId** on the client. It only works on server side. try to use **Meteor.userId()** .

Comment: lol, you are absolutely right. I just did it without 'this.userId' and now it works...Maybe I just did not get what 'this.userId' actually does...Could you maybe explain it to me? However, thanks.